# how do i get vim's foldtext to show the number of lines on the right side of the screen?

Tags: vim

I am trying to get the number of lines to show up on the right side of the screen, instead of near the left with the other text. Is this possible? My current .vimrc foldtext function concatenates the first two lines and keeps the current indent, followed by some dashes and then the number of lines:

```
function! MyFoldText()
    let line = getline(v:foldstart)
    let line2 = getline(v:foldstart + 1)
    let sub = substitute(line . "|" . line2, '/\*\|\*/\|{{{\d\=', '', 'g')
    let ind = indent(v:foldstart)
    let lines = v:foldend-v:foldstart + 1
    let i = 0
    let spaces = ''
    while i < (ind - ind/4)
        let spaces .= ' '
        let i = i+1
    endwhile
    return spaces . sub . ' --------(' . lines . ' lines)'
endfunction
```

So, using '|' as a screen edge, instead of

```
|    line1 | line2 --------(5 lines)-----------------|
```

the foldtext would be like this

```
|    line1 | line2 -------------------------(5 lines)|
```

p.s.
It would also be nice to get a few extra fixes, such as pulling current tabstop setting instead of hardcoding it as 4, and getting it to show the next actual code (skipping comments, whitespace, brackets, etc), instead of just concatenating the first two lines.

Comment: You can use winwidth('.') to calculate the width of the current window, but the foldtext likely won't be updated when the window size changes.  Personally I like having the line number aligned at 80 chars which also is a reminder of where to wrap my code.

Comment: Interesting. I've been trying to figure out how to implement that... how do you count how many characters are already in a string, to subtract that from winwidth and/or 80 chars?

Comment: vimscript has a `strlen()` function.  I suggest looking at `:help function-list`.  It's an extraordinary reference when scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the line below is what I use, sort of tailored to your code.  You will need to set offset to some value that fits your situation; I think you might want offset of around  8 or 9:

```
let offset = 8
return spaces . sub . repeat('-', winwidth(0)-strlen(spaces . sub) - offset) . '('. lines .')'
```

Comment: You should use `strdisplaywidth()` instead of `strlen()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example from the help of the [EightHeader](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4930) plugin which does exactly what you want:

If you don't like the default 'foldtext' you can customize it by setting to
`EightHeaderFolds()`.

For example the closed folds looks like this by default:

````
```+-- 45 lines: Fold level one
+--- 67 lines: Fold level two
````

If you would like to change it to this kind:

```
Fold level one................45 lines
  Fold level two..............67 lines
```

... then you can use this function:

```
let &foldtext = "EightHeaderFolds( '\\=s:fullwidth-2', 'left', [ repeat( '  ', v:foldlevel - 1 ), '.', '' ], '\\= s:foldlines . \" lines\"', '' )"
```